# authenticate users with certificate and Kerberos?

Tags: java, certificate, kerberos

i'm trying to authenticate users into a Kerberos realm with Java. I've already done the authentication with de Krb5LoginModule, and the users are correctly connected to the server with the Kerberos protocol.

Now i want to know if it's possible to athenticate users with a certificate, instead of using the Login+Password, in Kerberos, or ther is any other way to use a client certificate authentication with the Kerberos protocol?

thank you.

Comment: The standard way to authenticate Kerberos users using PKI is to use PKINIT protocol http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4556.txt  I just started the project to do exactly this,  but haven't gotten far enough yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you follow this thread, but the question you posed is a really interesting and doable. What you want to do is called Kerberos Single Sign-On authentication and can be done through JAAS (which is what you use now, I assume) and JGSS. You can check out this introduction from Oracle for [Kerberos SSO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jgss/single-signon.html). In general, setting up Kerberos SSO is a tedious task, but 100% doable. Let me know if you are interested and I could give you more information/guide you through the process of creating the certificates etc.

Regards,